# Slicing a circle's surface area in 3 equal parts not the usual way

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Is there a method to slice a circle's surface area in three equal parts by slicing the circle using two straight lines whose common point of origin is located on the circumference of the circle?

Comment: I am guessing that there must be some symmetry principle employed in the solution.

Comment: yes, there is, although the solution may not be analytical.

Comment: By "Is there a method", are you asking if such lines exist at all, or are you asking if you can construct the two straight lines in some restricted fashion, e.g. using ruler and compass?

Comment: Draw the picture and find the relation between areas enclosed by strings

Comment: I'm just guessing that it is possible - in principle - to trisect the circle area in equal parts either by analytical means or by compass and ruler by starting the trisection at a point on the circumference. The reality of the problem actually dawned on me when I needed to cut a circular pill of 3 mg in two pieces, one of 1 mg and the other of 2 mg. It is then that I realized that I didn't know of any mathematical or geometrical way that could help me tackle this problem in a simple or straightforward way!

Comment: Is the center of the circle given?

Answer (score 0):

Here you find instructions - some work left for you:
[image]

The goal is to find angle CBD.
Given BC, f, the triangle ABC is well defined for a given radius. We will create an equation for f in which the section BCD of the circle will be equal to the segments under the arcs.
The sector ABD ,ay be calculated as function of f - angle CAD is related to angle BAC. Angle BAC = Angle BAD. Angels BAC + BAD + CAD = 2$\pi$.
Does this detailed enough?